# Create a box using tcolorbox package?

Tags: tcolorbox

Regarding to question of voduchoangvu from [Create a color box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250069/create-a-color-box), I would also like to make a box like the figure below. Can you assist me with tex code using tcolorbox as well?

Thank you so much.
[image]

Answer (score 12):

Something like that?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,163,243}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{mytheorem}[1][]{
  enhanced jigsaw,colback=white,colframe=myblue,coltitle=myblue,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
  sharp corners,
  detach title,
  leftrule=22mm,
  underlay unbroken and first={\node[below,text=white,font=\sffamily\bfseries,align=center]
    at ([xshift=-11mm,yshift=-1mm]interior.north west) {THEOREM\\\thetcbcounter};},
  breakable,pad at break=1mm,
  #1,
  code={\ifdefempty{\tcbtitletext}{}{\tcbset{before upper={\tcbtitle\par\medskip}}}},
}


\begin{document}

\section{Test section}

\begin{mytheorem}[title=Normal Sampling Distributions]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mytheorem}

\begin{mytheorem}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mytheorem}

\begin{mytheorem}[title=Test]
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{mytheorem}

\end{document}
```