# spacing between text and frame of table?

Tags: tcolorbox

I use tcolorbox to define a new environment as suggested by Gonzalo at [Create a color box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250069/create-a-color-box). In that environment, I put the figure inside the frame as the code shown below. I want to adjust the space beetween the frame of table and the figure. In my case I want no space both sides: left and right; and no space for top and bottom. Can you tell me how to adjust it?[image]

code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within = chapter]{bang}[1][]{
colframe = myblue,
colback  = white,
coltitle = white,  
outer arc=0pt,
arc=0pt,
title    = {\bf Bảng ~\thetcbcounter} ,
#1,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{bang}
\includegraphics[scale=.78]{image/Chapter10/table10-1.png}
\end{bang}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set keys of `colorbox`: `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom` to `0pt`, and width of the inserted image to `\linewidth`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,163,243}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within = chapter]{bang}[1][]{
colframe = myblue,
colback  = white,
coltitle = white,  
outer arc=0pt,
arc=0pt,
left=0pt,
right=0pt,
top=0pt,
bottom=0pt,
title    = {\bf Bảng ~\thetcbcounter} ,
#1,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{bang}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}%{image/Chapter10/table10-1.png}
\end{bang}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Salim, I did follow your instruction, however, there is still a little bit space surrounding the figure (image). Does it need to set space = 0 surrounding for the image? If yes, how can I do it? Thanks (here is the link to photo : http://imgur.com/PsBROfb )

Comment: Try to add `boxsep=0pt` to tcolorbox keys

Comment: Hi Salim, one more thing if you can assist me. I would like to put the caption of "Partial Listing of Data on U.S.Inflation and Unemployment Rates, 1948-2003" after the "Bảng 10.1" for instance. how can I create an environment of "bang" with the title or caption so that apply for the whole document?

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer is:

```
\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within = chapter]{bang}[1][]{
colframe = myblue,
colback  = white,
coltitle = white,  
outer arc=0pt,
arc=0pt,
left=0pt,
right=0pt,
top=0pt,
bottom=0pt,
title    = {\bf Bảng ~\thetcbcounter \hspace{0.4cm} {#1}} ,
#1,
}
```

put the {#1} in the title argument.