# How to add label for referencing to customized newtcolorbox and body text font color change not working in case of page break

Tags: tcolorbox

I am very new to LaTeX. I needed customized colourbox and got this excellent customization provided by @Gonzalo Medina . I have got this from here [Create a color box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250069/create-a-color-box)
and just copy pasting the program

I need to have label for the example and also assumption macros for referencing.
Also, I found that when colorbox runs over multiple pages, the body text font colour (say I want red) changes to default black. How to correct this.
I have used \color{red} \Blindtext. Is it correct way to change text font colour. I found that it changes font colour on the same page, but for multipage colorbox, the text color resets to black.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,163,243}
\tcbset{mystyle/.style={
  breakable,
enhanced,
  outer arc=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  colframe=myblue,
  colback=myblue!20,
  attach boxed title to top left,
  boxed title style={
    colback=myblue,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    },
  title=Example~\thetcbcounter,
  fonttitle=\sffamily
  }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{example}[1][]{
  mystyle,
  title=Example~\thetcbcounter,
  }
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{assumption}[1][]{
  mystyle,
  colback=white,
  rightrule=0pt,
  toprule=0pt,
  title=Assumption SLR.\thetcbcounter,
  }

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\begin{example}
\color{red} \Blindtext % Is this correct way to change font color??
\end{example}
\begin{assumption}
\color{red} \Blindtext  % Is this correct way to change font color?
\end{assumption}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `label` option to every box for referencing. In following code I've done it adding a second mandatory parameter to `example` and `assumption` definitions. The optional parameter can be used to change default settings.

About color problem can be solved using the `colupper` option which fixes text color. Command `\color{red}` should not be used in this case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,163,243}
\tcbset{
mystyle/.style={
    breakable,
    enhanced,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    colframe=myblue,
    colback=myblue!20,
    attach boxed title to top left,
    boxed title style={
        colback=myblue,
        outer arc=0pt,
        arc=0pt,
   },
    title=Example~\thetcbcounter,
    fonttitle=\sffamily,
    colupper=red,
    }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{example}[2][]{
  mystyle,
  title=Example~\thetcbcounter,
  label=#2,
  #1
  }

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{assumption}[2][]{
  mystyle,
  colback=white,
  rightrule=0pt,
  toprule=0pt,
  title=Assumption SLR.\thetcbcounter,
  label=#2,
  #1
  }

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\begin{example}{A}
\Blindtext % Is this correct way to change font color??
\end{example}

As you can see in \ref{A} \dots

\begin{assumption}[colupper=myblue!50!red]{B}
\Blindtext  % Is this correct way to change font color?
\end{assumption}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi. But how can I add optional title after thetcbcounter. Actually I want to add the current section title after counter e.g. Example 1.1 Memory Devices in the heading of colorbox

Comment: @DebBijan What you want to do would be easier with a `\newtcbtheorem` box. You can find an example in updated section of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236230/1952). And better information in corresponding section of [`tcolorbox` documentation](http://texdoc.net7pkg/tcolorbox#page=339)