# How to add label for referencing in this example tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I am a new learner in LaTeX and want to add label for referencing to the below code done in `tcolorbox`. This program example was provided by @[Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250069/create-a-color-box) in his improved version where both `tcbcounter` and optional title is included.

I need a label option for both examples and assumptions.

Actually, after each section, I would be using blocks example and assumptions for each section so an option to also add current section title in the optional title text would be additionally of much help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,163,243}

\tcbset{mystyle/.style={
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  outer arc=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  colframe=myblue,
  colback=myblue!20,
  attach boxed title to top left,
  boxed title style={
    colback=myblue,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    top=3pt,
    bottom=3pt,
    },
  fonttitle=\sffamily
  }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{example}[1][]{
  mystyle,
  title=Example~\thetcbcounter,
  overlay unbroken and first={
      \path
        let
        \p1=(title.north east),
        \p2=(frame.north east)
        in
        node[anchor=west,font=\sffamily,color=myblue,text width=\x2-\x1] 
        at (title.east) {#1};
  }
}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{assumption}[1][]{
  mystyle,
  colback=white,
  rightrule=0pt,
  toprule=0pt,
  title=Assumption SLR.\thetcbcounter,
  overlay unbroken and first={
      \path
        let
        \p1=(title.north east),
        \p2=(frame.north east)
        in
        node[anchor=west,font=\sffamily,color=myblue,text width=\x2-\x1] 
        at (title.east) {#1};
  }
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\begin{example}
test
\end{example}
\begin{assumption}
test
\end{assumption}
\begin{example}[Optional title]
test
\end{example}
\begin{assumption}[Optional title with some more words for the example so it spans two lines]
test
\end{assumption}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the difference with your previous question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443801/how-to-add-label-for-referencing-to-customized-newtcolorbox-and-body-text-font-c/443809#443809

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an argument for the label

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,163,243}

\tcbset{mystyle/.style={
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  outer arc=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  colframe=myblue,
  colback=myblue!20,
  attach boxed title to top left,
  boxed title style={
    colback=myblue,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    top=3pt,
    bottom=3pt,
    },
  fonttitle=\sffamily
  }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{example}[2][]{
  mystyle,label=#2,
  title=Example~\thetcbcounter,
  overlay unbroken and first={
      \path
        let
        \p1=(title.north east),
        \p2=(frame.north east)
        in
        node[anchor=west,font=\sffamily,color=myblue,text width=\x2-\x1] 
        at (title.east) {#1};
  }
}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{assumption}[2][]{
  mystyle,label=#2,
  colback=white,
  rightrule=0pt,
  toprule=0pt,
  title=Assumption SLR.\thetcbcounter,
  overlay unbroken and first={
      \path
        let
        \p1=(title.north east),
        \p2=(frame.north east)
        in
        node[anchor=west,font=\sffamily,color=myblue,text width=\x2-\x1] 
        at (title.east) {#1};
  }
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\begin{example}{first}
test
\end{example}
\begin{assumption}{}
test
\end{assumption}
\begin{example}[Optional title]{}
test
\end{example}
\begin{assumption}[Optional title with some more words for the example so it
spans two lines]{fourth}
test
\end{assumption}

Box \ref{first}

box \ref{fourth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: As for your additional request:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62252/121799
\let\Sectionmark\sectionmark
\def\sectionmark#1{\def\Sectionname{#1}\Sectionmark{#1}}
\let\Subsectionmark\subsectionmark
\def\subsectionmark#1{\def\Subsectionname{#1}\Subsectionmark{#1}}
\let\Subsubsectionmark\subsubsectionmark
\def\subsubsectionmark#1{\def\Subsubsectionname{#1}\Subsubsectionmark{#1}}


\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,163,243}

\tcbset{mystyle/.style={
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  outer arc=0pt,
  arc=0pt,
  colframe=myblue,
  colback=myblue!20,
  attach boxed title to top left,
  boxed title style={
    colback=myblue,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    top=3pt,
    bottom=3pt,
    },
  fonttitle=\sffamily
  }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{example}[2][\Sectionname]{
  mystyle,label=#2,
  title=Example~\thetcbcounter,
  overlay unbroken and first={
      \path
        let
        \p1=(title.north east),
        \p2=(frame.north east)
        in
        node[anchor=west,font=\sffamily,color=myblue,text width=\x2-\x1] 
        at (title.east) {#1};
  }
}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{assumption}[2][\Sectionname]{
  mystyle,label=#2,
  colback=white,
  rightrule=0pt,
  toprule=0pt,
  title=Assumption SLR.\thetcbcounter,
  overlay unbroken and first={
      \path
        let
        \p1=(title.north east),
        \p2=(frame.north east)
        in
        node[anchor=west,font=\sffamily,color=myblue,text width=\x2-\x1] 
        at (title.east) {#1};
  }
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\begin{example}{first}
test
\end{example}
\begin{assumption}{x}
test
\end{assumption}
\begin{example}[Optional title]{y}
test
\end{example}
\begin{assumption}[Optional title with some more words for the example so it
spans two lines]{fourth}
test
\end{assumption}

Box \ref{first}

box \ref{fourth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide me a solution how to make the optional title to be the current section title so that every time I don't have to type the section title if needed... @marmot

Comment: @DebBijan Please see my update.